# Как можно узнать скорость соединения?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет Всем! Слышал где-то здесь кто-то хотел узнать скорость соединения с помощью php - что было очень хорошо, но как я понимаю php - работает на стороне сервера из-за этого он не может узнать скорость. А вот подумал а javascript сможет ли? Например сделать так чтобы пользователь скачивал какой-то файл и засекало время. Но как реализовать это на javas., я не знаю. Не кто не сталкивался с этим? Flash - не подойти, так как эти данные я не смогу записать в базу данных. Помогите!

Comment: А что собственно надо в базу записать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно делают на флеш. Там проще с измерениями, чем на js.

Как вариант: js+jQuery

Вставялете ВМРшку скажем мб на 5-10 (или несколько), начинаете отсчет. После $('#obj').load - заканчиваете.
А потом суете что-то большое оборатно POST-запросом, сервер после приема должен ответить - ок. Засекаете время от инициализации запроса - до ответа сервера (

```
    var d = new Date();
    window.begint = d.getTime();
   $.ajax(
   {
   url: 'uploadtest.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: ({'c': v}),
   success: function(data) {
         var d = new Date();
         window.endt = d.getTime();
         window.delta = window.endt - window.begint;
         }
    });
```

Дельта - в милисекундах. скорость = Объем / дельта * 1000 
После этого обрабатываете как нужно, отправляете не сервер и т.п.

Но на флеше, кончно, это будет точне и солиднее.
Естественно, вы сможете из флеша кинуть запрос на запись в БД, точно такой же как и из JS.

На флеше - примерно так. Мож где-то синтаксис напортачил. AS3.
Оно вам в любом случае понадобится, как-то ж нужно тестировать скорость ОтКлиента.

```
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
variables.var1 = 1;
variables.var2 = 2;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(); 
request.url = "http://www.  .com/spdt.php"; 
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
request.data = variables; 
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES; 
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler); 
try 
{ 
    loader.load(request); 
} 
catch (error:Error) 
{ 
    trace("Unable to load URL"); 
}

function completeHandler(event:Event):void 
{ 
    trace(event.target.data.welcomeMessage); 
}
```

Comment: А как на флешь? Я не представляю как от туда вынуть переменные

Comment: POST-запросом на сервер. Щас добавлю в ответ.

Я вообще хочу сказать, что вы решаете задачу, не до конца понимая принципов как её вообще решать...